# IFacebookManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I tried to do something like login with facebook in xamarin forms but i have Excpetion in constructor while app is loading
This is my code

```
 private readonly INavigationService _navigateService;
        private readonly IFacebookManager _facebookManager;
        private readonly IPageDialogService _dialogService;
```

and In **Constructor**

```
public LoginPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService dialogService , IFacebookManager facebookManager)
        {
            _dialogService = dialogService;
            _facebookManager = facebookManager;
            _navigateService = navigationService;
            IsLogedIn = false;
        }
```

but i got this exception and i don't know why

```
Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'System.Object', name = 'LoginPage'.
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor LGMobileApp.Views.LoginPage().
Exception is: ResolutionFailedException - Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'LGMobileApp.ViewModels.LoginPageViewModel', name = '(none)'.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, LGMobileApp.Helpers.IFacebookManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was: 
  Resolving LGMobileApp.ViewModels.LoginPageViewModel,(none)
  Resolving parameter 'facebookManager' of constructor LGMobileApp.ViewModels.LoginPageViewModel(Prism.Navigation.INavigationService navigationService, Prism.Services.IPageDialogService dialogService, LGMobileApp.Helpers.IFacebookManager facebookManager)
    Resolving LGMobileApp.Helpers.IFacebookManager,(none)

-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was: 
  Resolving LGMobileApp.Views.LoginPage,LoginPage (mapped from System.Object, LoginPage)
    Resolving LGMobileApp.Views.LoginPage,LoginPage
    Calling constructor LGMobileApp.Views.LoginPage()
```

In my app.cs

```
 protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {         
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage>();
        }
```

Any help ?

Comment: Have you set up `IFacebookManager` in your Unity container?

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: Well, that's your code, don't you already know how your DI system is working? For example, the `IPageDialogService` interface will be registered there, try and find that.

Comment: thank u @DavidG for replay i used prism.unity but it's the first time that i face this problem .. in my app.cs i always register for navigation only

Comment: @DavidG I edited the question and i think it's related with my container in my di how can i register this interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Prism does ensure that each container will resolve a concrete type for you as this is required to resolve your ViewModel, none of the containers can resolve an interface without a registration.

Any implementation that is available in your shared code can be done in your App.RegisterTypes like:

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.Register<IFacebookService, FacebookService>();
    }
}
```

If your implementation type is platform specific then you would need to add something like this to each of your platform projects like iOS, Android, etc.

```
public class PlatformInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.Register<IFacebookService, FacebookService>();
    }
}
```

Then when you load your app you would pass this into the ctor like:

`new App(new PlatformInitializer())`

Note that there are a couple of different ways to register a service. The one shown above registers the service as a transient so each time it is requested you will get a new instance. You can also call `RegisterSingleton` or `RegisterInstance` (if you have already created an instance) to get the same instance across your app

Comment: Thanks for reply @Dan S. in my case what do u mean by FacebookService I replaced it with Class Called FacebookManager which i create in each platform .. it still doesn't work I think something is missing

Comment: You need to register your dependencies. It doesn't matter what the dependency is, I just put IFacebookService as an example, I'm sure in your case it would be IFacebookManager. But you need to know how to construct an instance of the FacebookManager and make sure that the DI container has what it needs. For more complex setup's you may need to do `containerRegistry.GetContainer()` and then do a factory registration using the Unity API.